# Making a child theme in order to update the parent theme

Tags: child-theme, parent-theme

I'm really new to Wordpress development and had made a mistake by changing a parent theme for customizations instead of customizing a child theme. Not i cannot use the updates that my theme provider provides. Is there a way to fix this? Theme has WPbakery page builder as the primary building extension.

Comment: Do you keep a record of the files you've modified on your main theme?

Comment: unfortunately i did not :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my answer to [I modified the parent theme without creating a child theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/344150/i-modified-the-parent-theme-without-creating-a-child-theme/344175#344175) (similar question)

> As stated in a comment, any changes you made to the parent theme will
>   get overwritten with the theme update.
>
> But, you could copy all of the parent theme code to a new theme
>   folder, adjust the theme header on the copy to make it a child theme.
>   You could activate the copied theme, or make it a child theme, and
>   then dig out the changes you made to the theme. Put those changes in
>   another theme folder, adjusting it to a new child theme name, then
>   activate that new (2nd) child theme.
>
> All of this is a cautionary tale about the importance of child themes.

Comment: Addendum: Here's an article that shows you how to compare the files of two themes (the original parent theme and your modified version) so you can be sure you don't miss any of your changes: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-update-a-wordpress-theme-without-losing-customization/